# Factors Scientifically Shown to Affect Myopia

Tags: eye, vision

What are the main factors that have been reasonably established to affect myopia?

For example, here is a [study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18413523) which shows that children who spend a lot of time outside have far better eyesight than those who do not:

> RESULTS: The prevalence of myopia in 6- and 7-year-old children of
>   Chinese ethnicity was significantly lower in Sydney (3.3%) than in
>   Singapore (29.1%) (P < .001). Children in Sydney spent more time on
>   outdoor activities (13.75 vs 3.05 hours per week; P < .001), which was
>   the most significant factor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Myopia Reversible/Curable?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/13450/is-myopia-reversible-curable)